# Display stars rating around rounded profile image [CSS]

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design, frontend

Hi guys i'm creating rating system and i want to display the stars elements around profile image. I have profile image set to border-radius 50% which makes it rounded, but i'm struggle to set the div with the rates on the bottom of the profile image, what i'm looking for is something like this:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbbNE.png)

What i have by now it's this:

```css
body{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: #fff;
    
    }

    .avatar-inner{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }

    .avatar{
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .rate-holder{
        font-size: 25px;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #000;
    }
```

```html
<div class="avatar-holder">
        <div class="avatar-inner">
            <img class="avatar" src="https://i.ibb.co/bmfXcFw/avatar.png" alt="" srcset="">
            <div class="rate-holder">
                <span>*</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi popov, welcome to SO! You're not really showing what you did to get the stars circling around the avatar, essentially making us do the work for you. That's not how it works, please post your try as a [reprex]. Here's something that may give you some ideas [CSS layout: Circular navigation](https://csslayout.io/circular-navigation/). While it handles a circular menu, the base principle of `transform: rotate(..) translateX(..)` is the same.

Comment: @RenevanderLende thanks for the reply, the problem is that i have done nothing at this moment because i have no idea how to do it and what i'm searching for... i have only the ''example image'' for what i have to create. Thanks for the advice i will have a look on these and will try to work out something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [1]

> As @RenevanderLende mentioned in comments for doing that you can use
> `transform:rotate() translateX();`

Here's an example:

> and I should mention that in provided example you have to set icon
> sizes and their margins manually to match your photo-container
> dimensions

```js
// icons count
const count = 5;
// icons size in px
const size = 18;
// icons margin in px
const marign = 4;
// icons position in deg
  // e.g. if you wanna position all icons at the bottom side use: 55
  // e.g. if you wanna position all icons at the left side use: 120
  // e.g. if you wanna position all icons at the top side use: 240
  // e.g. if you wanna position all icons at the right side use: 330
const position = 0;

// get list of all photo containers
const photoContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".photo-container");

// loop through each container and generate rating stars
[...photoContainer].forEach((container) => {
  // gets radius of the container
  const r = container.offsetHeight / 2;
  const offset = (size / Math.PI) * -1;

  const ratingContainer = document.createElement("div");
  ratingContainer.className = "rating-container";
  const iconsHolder = document.createElement("div");
  iconsHolder.className = "icons-holder";

  const pos = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    // creates the angles array
    pos.push(i * (size + offset + marign));

    // creates some holders in a circularly positioned way, to hold the rating stars
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.position = "absolute";
    div.style.display = "block";
    div.style.height = `${size}px`;
    div.style.width = `${size}px`;
    // sets the icons positions circularly
    div.style.transform = `rotate(${pos[i]}deg) translateX(${r - size + Math.abs(offset)}px)`;

    // creates the star icons
    const icon = document.createElement("span");
    icon.className = "icon fa fa-star";
    icon.style.fontSize = `${size}px`;

    // arranges icons vertically(90deg)
      // remove this part to see what happens
    icon.style.transform = `rotate(${pos[i] * -1}deg)`;

    div.append(icon);
    iconsHolder.append(div);
  }

  // changes the all icons position
  iconsHolder.style.transform = `rotate(${position}deg)`;
  ratingContainer.append(iconsHolder);
  container.append(ratingContainer);
});
```

```css
.photo-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rating-container {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
}

.rating-container .icons-holder {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.icons-holder>div {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.icons-holder>div .icon {
  color: orange;
}

.icons-holder>div .icon:hover {
  color: darkgoldenrod;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="photo-container">
  <img style="width: 100%;" src="https://i.ibb.co/bmfXcFw/avatar.png" />
</div>
<div class="photo-container">
  <img style="width: 100%;" src="https://i.ibb.co/bmfXcFw/avatar.png" />
</div>
```

---

Update:

### [2]

You can also do it without using css `transform` (explanations are provided as comments in code.)

> Example 1:

```js
function ratingStars(root, options) {
  // returns width and height of an element
  const getRadius = (element) => {
    return Math.round(element.offsetWidth / 2);
  };
  // takes radius, degrees returns x,y
  const pos = (r, theta) => {
    return {
      // theta * (Math.PI / 180)  converts radians to degrees
      x: Math.round(r * Math.cos(theta * (Math.PI / 180))),
      y: Math.round(r * Math.sin(theta * (Math.PI / 180))),
    };
  };

  // default options
  let op = {
    count: 6,
    icons_class: "rating-icons",
    rotate: 0, // deg
    clock_wise: true, // boolean
    size: 28, // pt
    icons_margin: 3.8, // px
    edge_margin: 0, // px
  };
  // merges custom options with defaults
  op = { ...op,
    ...options
  };

  // gets radius of the root element
  const radius = getRadius(root); //pixels
  if (radius) {
    // creates the main holder of all icons
    const rating = document.createElement("div");
    rating.style.position = "absolute";
    // moves the holder to the center of the root element
    rating.style.left = `${radius - op.size / 2}px`;
    rating.style.top = `${radius - op.size / 2}px`;
    root.append(rating);


    // generates the required degrees based on count and pushes to the degs
    let degs = [];
    // runs if the clock_wise is set on true
    if (op.clock_wise == true)
      for (let i = 0; i < op.count; i++) degs.push(Math.round(i * (op.size / Math.PI + op.icons_margin)));
    // runs if the clock_wise is set on false
    else
      for (let i = 0; i < op.count; i++) degs.push(-Math.round(i * (op.size / Math.PI + op.icons_margin)));

    // loops through the degrees and create a holder for each icon
    degs.forEach((deg) => {
      // creates a holder for each icon
      let icon = document.createElement("div");
      icon.style.position = "absolute";
      icon.style.textAlign = "center";
      // positions the holders in a circular way using pos() function that we created first
      icon.style.left = `${pos(radius - op.size / 2 - op.edge_margin, deg + op.rotate).x}px`;
      icon.style.top = `${pos(radius - op.size / 2 - op.edge_margin, deg + op.rotate).y}px`;
      // appends the star icons the the holder
      icon.innerHTML = `<span style="font-size: ${op.size * 0.75}pt;" class="${op.icons_class} fa fa-star"></span>`;
      rating.append(icon);
    });
  }
}
const avatar = document.querySelector(".avatar");


ratingStars(avatar);
```

```css
.avatar {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
}

.rating-icons {
  color: orange;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.rating-icons:hover {
  color: yellow;
  transform: scale(1.15) rotate(70deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="avatar">
  <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/300?img=11" style="height: 100%" />
</div>
```

> Example 2:
> (includes an example for each option)

```js
function ratingStars(root, options) {
  // returns width and height of an element
  const getRadius = (element) => {
    if (element.offsetHeight == element.offsetWidth) return Math.round(element.offsetWidth / 2);
    else console.error("the given element isn't a circle");
  };
  // takes radius, degrees returns x,y
  const pos = (r, theta) => {
    return {
      // theta * (Math.PI / 180)  converts radians to degrees
      x: Math.round(r * Math.cos(theta * (Math.PI / 180))),
      y: Math.round(r * Math.sin(theta * (Math.PI / 180))),
    };
  };

  // default options
  let op = {
    count: 6,
    icons_class: "rating-icons",
    rotate: 0, // deg
    clock_wise: true, // boolean
    size: 20, // pt
    icons_margin: 8, // px
    edge_margin: 0, // px
  };
  // merges custom options with defaults
  op = { ...op,
    ...options
  };

  // gets radius of the root element
  const radius = getRadius(root); //pixels
  if (radius) {
    // creates the main holder of all icons
    const rating = document.createElement("div");
    rating.style.position = "absolute";
    // moves the holder to the center of the root element
    rating.style.left = `${radius - op.size / 2}px`;
    rating.style.top = `${radius - op.size / 2}px`;
    root.append(rating);

    // generates the required degrees based on count and pushes to the degs
    let degs = [];
    // runs if the clock_wise is set on true
    if (op.clock_wise == true)
      for (let i = 0; i < op.count; i++) degs.push(Math.round(i * (op.size / Math.PI + op.icons_margin)));
    // runs if the clock_wise is set on false
    else
      for (let i = 0; i < op.count; i++) degs.push(-Math.round(i * (op.size / Math.PI + op.icons_margin)));

    // loops through the degrees and create a holder for each icon
    degs.forEach((deg) => {
      // creates a holder for each icon
      let icon = document.createElement("div");
      icon.style.position = "absolute";
      icon.style.textAlign = "center";
      // positions the holders in a circular way using pos() function that we created first
      icon.style.left = `${pos(radius - op.size / 2 - op.edge_margin, deg + op.rotate).x}px`;
      icon.style.top = `${pos(radius - op.size / 2 - op.edge_margin, deg + op.rotate).y}px`;
      // appends the star icons the the holder
      icon.innerHTML = `<span style="font-size: ${op.size * 0.75}pt;" class="${op.icons_class} fa fa-star"></span>`;
      rating.append(icon);
    });
  }
}

const avatars = document.querySelectorAll(".avatar");
ratingStars(avatars[0]);
ratingStars(avatars[1], {
  icons_class: 'rating-icons red'
});
ratingStars(avatars[2], {
  rotate: 143
});
ratingStars(avatars[3], {
  clock_wise: false
});
ratingStars(avatars[4], {
  size: 28
});
ratingStars(avatars[5], {
  icons_margin: 20
});
ratingStars(avatars[6], {
  edge_margin: 20
});
ratingStars(avatars[7], {
  count: 4,
  icons_class: 'rating-icons green',
  rotate: 50,
  clock_wise: true,
  size: 30,
  icons_margin: 40,
  edge_margin: 15
});
ratingStars(avatars[8], {
  count: 15
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at 10% 20%, rgba(90, 92, 106, 1) 0%, rgba(32, 45, 58, 1) 81.3%);
}

.avatar {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
}

.rating-icons {
  color: orange;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.rating-icons:hover {
  color: darkgoldenrod;
  transform: scale(1.15) rotate(70deg);
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

.red:hover {
  color: darkred;
}

.green {
  color: green;
}

.green:hover {
  color: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div style="display: flex">
  <div class="avatar" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
    <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/300?random=1" style="height: 100%" />
  </div>
</div>
<div style="display: flex">
  <div class="avatar">
    <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/300?random=1" style="height: 100%" />
  </div>
  <div class="avatar">
    <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/300?random=2" style="height: 100%" />
  </div>
  <div class="avatar">
    <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/300?random=3" style="height: 100%" />
  </div>
  <div class="avatar">
    <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/300?random=5" style="height: 100%" />
  </div>
</div>
<div style="display: flex">
  <div class="avatar">
    <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/300?random=6" style="height: 100%" />
  </div>
  <div class="avatar">
    <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/300?random=7" style="height: 100%" />
  </div>
  <div class="avatar">
    <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/300?random=8" style="height: 100%" />
  </div>
  <div class="avatar">
    <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/300?random=4" style="height: 100%" />
  </div>
</div>
```